# When would I register a crm 2011 online plugin for pre-validation stage?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I understand that a plugin registered for pre-validation executes outside of the database transaction but I'm not sure I can think of a scenario when this would be preferable to pre-operation. Can someone give me an example of where pre-validation registration might be useful?

Comment: As @glosrob already mentioned: this is not CRM Online specific. The name of the stage points to its usage. If you have to validate something **prior** the CRM operation, use this stage.

Comment: @ckeller yes, didn't think it was crm online specific although seem to remember reading somwhere that certain stages were only available online. "pre-operation" sounds like it happens before the particular message processing occurs but as glosrob points out, this is not always true

Comment: it's in the plugin registration tool where it seems to be saying that pre-operation is only available for crm 2011 online. See pic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515.aspx#bkmk_RegStep)

Comment: All stages are available for On-Premise and Online version. There is no difference. There is however a difference between CRM 4 and CRM 2011. I can't see any detail in the picture which leads to your assumption.

Comment: Agree with @ckeller here - the 'CRM 2011 only' refers to those stages only being available for 2011 version of CRM. The Plugin Reg tool can be used for CRM 2011 and CRM4 (I think), which is why they specify on the UI.

Comment: ok. So crm 4.0 has what they call a "pre-event" stage but in crm 2011 language is a "pre-validate" (i.e. outside transaction). Both 4.0 and 2011 have a post-operation. Difference seems to be 4.0 post-operation executes outside the transaction whereas 2011 post-operation executes within the transaction. 2011 "pre-operation" (within transaction) doesn't exist in 4.0 world. Think I'm clear(ish) now...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have a few plugins registered on the 'PreValidation' event although this is on premise, not online.

I did not write these specific plugins myself but I can describe one and give the justification for using 'PreValidation' rather than 'PreOperation'.

Entity: Account

Event: Delete

Logic: Plugin runs pre validation. Checks that there are no contacts referencing any of the account's addresses. If any are found, stop execution. If not, delete account.

e.g.

Account 'Stackoverflow' has address 'Jeff Attwood's House' and Contact 'glosrob'. 'glosrob' is referencing 'Jeff Attwood's House' through a customisation. If a user selects to delete 'StackOverflow', we should detect 'glosrob' is referencing an address and prevent the delete.

The reasoning behind this was the developer found that at the PreOperation stage, some aspects of the delete had already happened, namely the cascade deletes. The logic of the plugin requires us to check all contacts - by registering at PreOperation, contacts under the account had already been deleted, rendering the check obsolete.

In our previous scenario, when the user selected to delete 'StackOverflow' Account, the Contact 'glosrob' would be deleted before the plugin runs. Therefore when the plugin did run afterwards, it would allow the delete.

As with most things in CRM, it all comes down to requirements and solutions, but I think that gives you an idea of why/when you might use a PreValidation stage. We have a few others with similar reasoning that run on the 'Delete' event.

Comment: great explanation thanks. i wasn't aware that cascade deletes would have occurred prior to pre-operation stage. It seems a bit strange that anything occurs before pre-operation but I suppose it depends on what is meant by "operation".

Comment: Yeah I can understand the confusion. I guess the operation is specifically deleting the account, rather than deleting the account's contacts, leads etc. etc.

Comment: been thinking about the scenario you describe. Maybe I misunderstand here but if the account deletion was to fail for some other reason and the pre-operation plugin threw an exception, how would the cascade deletes be reversed? If the cascade deletes happen before the pre-operation stage then they happen outside the transaction so i'm not sure how crm would be able to reverse them. That could leave a situation where the account delete ultimately failed but some of the related cascaded info was deleted. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah that is down to my explanation I think. Essentially, at the pre validation stage, nothing has happened. At the pre operation stage, the cascade deletes have happened but they occur inside the transaction, meaning they can be rolled back. If you excuse the crudeness of the diagram (lol), I have tried to explain what I mean http://i.imgur.com/sz84B.png

Comment: diagram very clear. get it now. good to know about how cascade deletes work. cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The Microsoft MB2-876 CRM exam mentions that it covers 'cascading events' but I couldn't find much explanation about what this might mean.  The diagram cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 2):

I know its very old post, came here while digging for an answer for the same question...
Later I found one key point from MSDN on the same topic and i thought it would be helpful If I post the infromation over here for all..

The Prevalidation plugin would happen prior to the security checks. For ex: If an account is "VIP" account and you dont want this account record to be deleted (no matter even he is a super user/admin), then this better can happen in pre validation. Because at that time you are not really bothered about who the user is and what sort of permissions he has (even he may not have any permissions to delete any records in the system), CRM will go and check the database for the user's security roles during the pre operation and that is where the first database hit would happen.. before that it self, we can stop the exucution of the plugin based on our validation rules..

I hope that make sense...

Thank you

Regards
Srikanth